# How to test Rest-APIs that rely on persistence with arquillian

Tags: java, rest, jpa, jax-rs

I would like to test a class that provides a rest endpoint via JAX-RS. This class depends on a JPA `EntityManager` an thus on a database which needs to be populated prior to test execution. I saw solutions for database population like dbunit, but I want to populate the data directly from my test class (or delegated via [object mother pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ObjectMother.html)). But when testing rest endpoints I need to use the annotation option `@Deployment(testable = false)` which refuses me to inject the `EntityManager` into my test class.

**So how can I solve this situation?**

Or are there any better best practices? (maybe mocking, but that's also not possible for black box tests)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a bean to generate your test data:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class TestDataGenerator {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em; 

    @PostConstruct
    private void generateTestData() {
        // Generate your test data
    }
}
```

The `TestDataGenerator` class defined above is annotated with [`@Singleton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Startup.html) (ensuring there will be only one instance of the class) and [`@Startup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html) (for eager initialization during the application startup sequence).

Add the `TestDataGenerator` class to your Arquillian deployment:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyArquillianTest {

    private Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    @Deployment
    @RunAsClient
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addClasses(TestDataGenerator.class, ...)
            .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void testAPI(@ArquillianResource URL deploymentUrl) {
        // Test your REST service
        WebTarget target = client.target(deploymentUrl.toURI()).path("api");
    }
}
```

Observe that [`@RunAsClient`](http://docs.jboss.org/arquillian/spi/1.0.3.Final/org/jboss/arquillian/container/test/api/RunAsClient.html) is equivalent to [`@Deployment(testable = false)`](http://docs.jboss.org/arquillian/spi/1.0.3.Final/org/jboss/arquillian/container/test/api/Deployment.html).

The [`@ArquillianResource`](http://docs.jboss.org/arquillian/spi/1.0.3.Final/org/jboss/arquillian/test/api/ArquillianResource.html) annotation allows you to inject the [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) to test your web application.

Comment: That is an interesting approach. However I wonder if this can be considered as bad practice due to mixing the test data generator with the source code to be tested. Also it is necessary to have a specific generator bean for every test case. I would like to have an object mother that is capable of creating a set of generic test data which can then be customized in the test class itself.

Comment: @thomas.mc.work Since you have different source folders to store your application (`src/main`) and your tests (`src/test`), and you use the `src/test` content for test purpose only, this approach will work fine. You are just creating a deployment file that should be tested and embedding your test data with it. In the `generateTestData()` method, you can delegate the test data generation to your object mothers.

Answer (score 0):

For tests, I usually try and separate black box and unit testing completely (I suppose it's a preference on how you do it).

For example, my REST Api could rely on whatever it wants, but usually it doesn't do much but call my database layer or some sort of facade accessing my DB layer. The objects are injected, yes, but usually I make the fields package private, which meant that you can set them from the same package (which works with Junit as well).

For example:

```
public class Facade1 {
@Inject
Facade facade;

public void doSomething() { ... }

}
```

This class represents my REST API. I could test doSomething by simply adding a mock object as facade. Mind you, this is a quite useless test, but you get the idea. Unit tests should happen in isolation with as much mocking as possible.

Now testing the actual Rest API I usually resort to a python integration tester. Python has nice http libraries that allow you to make request very easily.

For that, I set up a staging environment for my Rest Server. The environment is a live-like representation for testing. Everything there needs to works and needs to be on the same version as the production deployment.

I then use python to poke my REST Api and verify the responses. Since I've set up my staging environment I have complete control over database content. Therefore it is easy for me to test that all responses are correct.

My typical process then is:

1. Compile
2. Build
3. Deploy
4. Integration test

I hope that helps. If you want clearer examples, you might want to post a bit more code as it's a bit hard to imagine for me what it is exactly you'd like to do :)